# ошибка при обращении к столбцам

Tags: php, mysql

Происходит ошибка, и не могу понять в чем причина, все перепробовал уже вроде как.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`' in page.php on line 8

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); $id = $_POST['id'];

$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user_name", "pass"); 
mysqli_select_db($link,"base_name"); 
$result = mysqli_query(SELECT * FROM `space` WHERE 'id'=$id);

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в отсутствие кавычек видимо:

```php
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `space` WHERE id=".$id);
```

Comment: **Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in page.php on line 8**

исправил на ваш вариант, теперь ошибка такого вида

Comment: @SloGS а вы читайте что написано в предупреждении и прочитайте описание функции `mysqli_query`....

Comment: Извиняюсь, не увидел вначале других ошибок. Скопировал из топика.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я читал, написано было что пропущен символ, но я не понимл где, теперь узнал, спасибо!

Comment: @SloGS не символ а параметр......что значит не понимали где? в документации четко написано `mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`, где `link` - Идентификатор соединения, `query` - запрос...... читайте внимательно доки

Comment: Понимал что на восьмой строке, но что именно не то не знал!